# Saving user info in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make an AI that when you input your name on first run, it will save it and your options for that user and automatically opens that user next time you open the program. Such as when you meet someone in real life, you can identify them next time you meet them. As this program is designed as a personal assistant, it only requires one person/user. I need the program to be able to store and load info about the User.

I have no idea how to do this and the internet doesn't really help

Comment: you can use `ConfigParser`, it's a class for reading and writing config files. see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html , also, you can save the info in a class and then use `pickle.dump` and `pickle.load` to save and load the object created into and from a file. link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: I'm just curious - what kind of programming knowledge or experience or expertise do you have?

Comment: None.. why? do you have any tips for me?

Comment: @WilfRosenbaum - I have decent knowledge, but not much experience, cus im 15, I learn pretty quickly

Comment: @בנימיןכהן - I tried using Pickle a while back, but failed miserably...

Comment: Sorry @בנימיןכהן - my question was directed towards SirBlazzit.

Comment: and that, Ladies and Gentlemen, is why we tag people. :)

Comment: Learn python and basic sw engineering first. Then AI. Seriously. Otherwise you will drown in a glass of water every time you are thirsty. Apart from that, you can also use a database, in case the data structures to save grow and interrelate

Comment: @WilfRosenbaum - This is the first AI I have attemped to make, I usually make pointless programs - e.g. Fake V-Bucks Generators to sell at school, password crackers for zip files... etc. this is the first serious project.

Comment: @SirBlazzit - ok then. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like pickle:

```
import pickle

data = {}  # here's where data about the user is in the program
try:
    with open('info.pickle', 'rb') as handle: # check if data is already stored in a .pickle file. If it is, load it into our data variable
        data = pickle.load(handle)
except:
    data = {'Name': input("Name?\n")} # otherwise make a data variable and ask for a name
print(data['Name']) # display the name
data[input("Quality\n")] = input("Data\n") # ask user for other qualities about them
with open('info.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(data, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) # save our new info into the pickle file
```

Comment: So how does this work, im not familiar with Pickle much

Comment: added some comments